# "New Answer has been posted" drops markup tools into input?

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, answers

This actually has happened to me a couple times before now, so I figure now is a fine time to report. Running XP, on IE8. FF is on another machine so I don't always have the leisure to test it there. Anyway...

When composing an answer, if the popup for "X new answers have been posted" shows up, I'll click it to see if I should abandon my progress or not. The text of them looks funny (but I think that's probably <kbd>by-design</kbd> for rendering), but the real problem is that the toolbar is shoved into my post editor. Screenshot for reference.

**EDIT**

Just found out this morning, it doesn't appear completely fixed. In fact, the buttons are further down than before, probably impacted by the fact that the buttons are now cutting into the edit field from the start (see second screenshot).

[image: No tooltip provided]
**Second Screenshot**
[image: No tooltip provided]
[Old Image](https://i.imgur.com/q52fi.png)

Comment: are you in IE7 emulation mode by any chance?

Comment: Fix looks good for me in IE8. Just verified in a new IE8 browser window with another window open to post a 2nd answer.. edit: verified multiple times with large & small questions and large & small amounts of text. It looks correct for me in IE8 after clicking "load new answers", in all cases. Maybe clear your browser cache?

Comment: @Jeff As far as I know, I'm not emulating anything. But I just tested on IE8 on a different computer, and it looks fine there. So it may be something wonky on this machine. I did two cache clearings, no good. I'm chalking this up to no-repro, by now.

Comment: Well, since it's fixed for every other machine (including machines I own!), it's complete as far as anyone should worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed now (on meta only at the moment). Can you give it a shot?